# has_many and belongs_to associations in factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, factory-bot

I have these models that I'm trying to create factories for using factory_girl.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :baz
end

class Baz < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foos
end
```

I'm not sure how to create the factories without creating a loop where the factories endlessly call each other.

```
Factory.define :foo do |f|
  f.after_create do |ff|
    ff.baz = Factory(:baz)
  end
end

Factory.define :baz do |f|
  f.after_create do |ff|
    ff.foos = [Factory.create(:foo)]
  end
end
```

I realize I can just leave out `ff.foos = [Factory.create(:foo)]` in the `baz` factory, but then in my `baz` tests I'm forced to used `foo.baz` instead of just using `baz`. Am I forced to use the `baz` object by fetching it out of a `foo` factory in my tests? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the **Associations** section of [the Getting Started guide](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md)

### Added

So, you need to use that syntax from that section, ie. in your `Foo` declaration you need:

```
Factory.define :foo do |f|
  f.association :baz
end
```

No `after_create` needed for a `belongs_to` association.

Comment: Yes, I've read the documentation. It does not really answer my question.

Comment: What if the foreign key cannot be null? You need an after_create callback then.